# How to convert an ONNX model with dynamic input shape to Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, onnx

I am trying to convert an ONNX model with a dynamic input shape to TensorFlow format using the **onnx_tf** package. I am using **TensorFlow 2.11.0**, **ONNX 1.13.0**, and **onnx_tf 1.10.0**. The input to the model contains 3 arrays: the data with dynamic shape (1, None) and 2 arrays with fixed shapes (2,1,64). When I run the following code, I get on the last line a "ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank" :

```
# Imports
import onnx
from onnx import version_converter
import os
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

# load onnx model
model_dir = r'model\vad'
model_name = 'vad.onnx'
onnx_model = onnx.load(os.path.join(model_dir,'onnx', model_name))  # load onnx model

# Export to Tensorflow
os.makedirs(os.path.join(model_dir ,'tensorflow'), exist_ok=True)
tf_rep = prepare(onnx_model)  # prepare tf representation
tf_rep.export_graph(os.path.join(model_dir,'tensorflow','vad'))  # export the model
```

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?